# Issue parsing yaml file

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I have the following struct which filled after parsing yaml file
The issue is that the quote is missing

> File in.yaml

e.g.

```
_schema: "3.0.0"
bar:
- one
```

> File out.yaml

```
_schema: 3.0.0
bar:
- one
```

As you can see I got **3.0.0**  instead the **“3.0.0”** , Any idea how to overcome this

This is a small program which I've created to demonstrate the issue

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Config struct {
    Schema string `yaml:"_schema"`
    Bar []string
}

func main() {

    cfg := Config{}
    source, err := ioutil.ReadFile("in.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(source), &cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    y, _ := yaml.Marshal(&cfg)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("out.yaml", y, 0644)}

}
```

Comment: Why are the quotes required? Since it is just a string it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML standard doesn't require quoting of all values, only when you want to use escape sequences or you are using certain characters.

This library you are using adds `"..."` around the string only when it's necessary. For example if you used a colon in string (try: "3:0:0") it'll stay in double quotes.